# CiviEvent Scheduled Reminders and manual recipients

Tags: civievent, scheduled-reminders

I've setup a very simple scheduled email reminder for an event that sends to registered participants as well as the site admin, whom I've added as a manual recipient, 2 hours before the event start date. The reminder sends to the registered participants as it should, but it sends to the site admin at the very next cron cycle, even if it's days or weeks before the event. The admin then never gets the reminder at the 2 hour before event mark.

Another thing I've noticed is that the tokens in the email work for the registered participants, but not for the manually added recipient. {event.title} always resolves as the very first event I ever created in the manual recipient email.

Has anyone else had this problem? I'm running CiviCRM 5.8.2 on Drupal.

Comment: I am having this problem as well. Did you find any solutions or answers?

Comment: unfortunately no, still having this problem.